# How to pass ArrayList object (from session) into variable declared in JSP page

Tags: javascript, java, session, arraylist, autocomplete

I have created one ArrayList in JavaAction class `List products = miscDao.getInsSubProdsByLoc("Y", locCntryId);` and set it into the session using  `session.setAttribute("products", products );`

Now, I want to use this array list in my JSP file. So I did

```
<%
ArrayList<String> populated = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("products");

%>
```

When I checked above List, we are getting objects into that array. I want values corresponding to that objects to be saved in the form of array in javascript function like below.

```
var Countries = ['ARGENTINA', 
            'AUSTRALIA', 
            'BRAZIL', 
            'BELARUS', 
            'BHUTAN',
            'CHILE', 
            'CAMBODIA', 
            'CANADA', 
            'CHILE', 
            'DENMARK', 
            'DOMINICA'];
```

can anyone please help me in this. Actually I am creating autocomplete, for that I need to pass values from that arraylist to textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> populated = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("products");
```

Once you have this, print each one of them using JSTL:

```
<c:forEach items="${populated}" var="item">
   ${item}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: This is the function, where I need to store these values ..... function BindControls() { var products = [];

Comment: can I write it like this var products = <c:forEach items="${populated}" var="item">
   ${item}<br>
</c:forEach> .... is that fine, sorry I don't know jstl. Please excuse me

Comment: Well, thats wrong.  JSTL probably the easiest way of implementing what you want. Read more here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm

Answer (score 0):

In the servlet code, first you save your list in the request object, and use the name "countryList" or anything that you want:

```
request.setAttribute("countryList",listObj);
```

When you arrive to your JSP, it's necessary to retrieve the list from the request, and for that you just need the request.getAttribute(...) method.
like:

```
request.getAttribute("requiredList");

<%  
// retrieve your list from the request, with casting 
ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("countryList");

// print the information about every category of the list
for(String country: countryList) {
    out.println(country);
}
%>
```

Comment: But I want these values to get store in that format I have given var Countries = ['ARGENTINA', 
            'AUSTRALIA', 
            'BRAZIL', 
            'BELARUS', 
            'BHUTAN',
            'CHILE', 
            'CAMBODIA', 
            'CANADA', 
            'CHILE', 
            'DENMARK', 
            'DOMINICA'];  how will I get that.

Comment: format or sorting order because format will be same and also array list maintain the insertion order